# Extend a record as you would a class (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an unusual need for my application.

I want users to be able to set `defaults` that their users can extend to make their own `options`

Basically, users will customize their own control panels for use by their end users.

**Example**

John is my user, he creates two `defaults`:

```
name: 'Age'
value: 21
```

and

```
name: 'Subscribe to newsletter'
value: false
```

To be clear, this is being created by my user, John in my Rails application. I am not hardcoding the above data in my model. The `default` is the model and it has a `name` and a `value`

Now Suzie will see her own version of John's control panel with these two `defaults` and extend them with her own `options`

```
name: 'Age'
value: 18
```

and

```
name: 'Subscribe to newsletter'
value: false
```

I understand that ruby has its own native way to extend objects from classes, but creating a class from a record is hurting my brain. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: You can't create classes from records, nor do you need to. You just need to create two models, one for defaults, one for customized defaults which points to the parent default.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment that you don't need to create any new classes.

Often, when dealing with default values, the behavior of Hash#merge is useful.

default_values.merge(user_values) will give you a single hash that contains all of the values, but where they conflict, will take those from the second hash. See [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-merge).

Without knowing exactly what your database schema looks like, and assuming that john and suzie are User objects with a relationship to Defaults and Options, then it could be something like:

```
default_values = Hash[*john.defaults.map{ |d| [d.name, d.value] }.flatten]
user_values = Hash[*suzie.options.map{ |o| [o.name, o.value] }.flatten]
default_values.merge(user_values)
```